# Error reading each file from dir in vb

Tags: vb.net

I am getting this error while i am trying to read one by one all files in a dir, and also reading the text inside

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It is going good only for the first file , but when it starts another loop and gets the secound file from that folder there comes the problem.
This is my code

```
Dim theString As String
        Dim path As String
        Dim StrFile, str_5 As String
        Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
        Dim file As TextStream
        Dim line As String

        'theString = ""
        path = "C:\IN\"

        StrFile = Dir(path & "*.txt")

        Do While StrFile <> ""

            file = fso.OpenTextFile(path & StrFile)
            Do While Not file.AtEndOfLine
                line = file.ReadLine
                If InStr(1, line, line.Substring(142, 1), vbTextCompare) = 5 Then
                    'Debug.Print(StrFile)
                    str_5 = str_5 & line

                End If
            Loop

            file.Close()
            file = Nothing
            fso = Nothing

            StrFile = Dir()
        Loop
```

Comment: does it say exactly which line the error occurs on? Or can you debug and set breakpoints to find out the exact location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: it gives me the error on this line     
  file = fso.OpenTextFile(path & StrFile)

Comment: Obvious bug: you are setting `fso = Nothing` inside the (outer) loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for other people with the same problem, the answer is to just remove this line 
fso = Nothing